# seconds part of string representing date time is dropped when reading from time from CSV file

Tags: python

I have a CSV with time stamp data looks like this:

```
22/11/2018  10:21:34
```

And im parsing it this way : `currentTime = dt.strptime(line[0], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

I have problem when parsing rows of this kind (when the seconds equal 00):

```
22/11/2018  10:21:00
```

i get : `time data '22/11/2018 10:21' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'`

Comment: Are you sure the file really contains `:00` when the seconds are 0? The error message indicates that the time is missing that part of it.

Comment: The result I get from `strptime()` for the second string is `2018-11-22 10:21:00`.

Comment: Actually its weird. I now have opened it with notepad and see indeed the stamp is only 22/11/2018 10:21. But when i opening with excel i see 22/11/2018 10:21:00. Any idea what should i do?